# Como verificar valor do ID de uma tag e quantas vezes se repete com Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Pessoal tenho um trecho de um código referente a imagem abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na primeira div mostra uma listagem de alunos. Na segunda os alunos que o usuário escolher para seu grupo, conforme ele clica em cima de cada aluno tenho uma função jquery que inseri o aluno na div grupo e o limita a inserir no máximo 5 (fora o próprio usuário) e o processo inverso para remover os alunos do grupo, a cada click o manda de volta para div alunos. Preciso aplicar uma regra de negocio onde obrigatoriamente o usuário deve escolher dois alunos de cada curso, dessa forma pensei em colocar o ID de cada curso no ID da `li`, mas não sei como ler esses id e permitir somente dois alunos de cada curso no seu grupo.

Tentei usar `.length` com um `if` logo depois que verifica a quantidade máxima pra fazer as comparações, mas não rolou. ideias ou exemplos pra ajudar por favor?

Codigo **JQUERY**:

```
  $(function(){
   $(".aluno").click(function(){ //EVENTO CLICK

    var c = 1; //CONTADOR
    $("#grupo .aluno").each(function(){
      c++;
    });

    if(($(this).parent().attr("id") == "lista") && c <=  5) { //VERIFICA EM QUAL DIV PERTENCE E QUANT. MÁXIMA
       $("#grupo").append(this); //ANEXA NA DIV GRUPO
       $("#grupo .aluno").addClass("selecionado"); //INSERIR CLASSE COM A COR DIFERENTE

    } else {
       $("#lista").append(this); //ANEXA NA DIV ALUNOS
       $("#lista .aluno").removeClass("selecionado"); //REMOVER CLASSE
    }

  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

 <div class="lista-alunos">
    <h3></i>Alunos</h3>
    <ol id="lista">
      <li class="aluno" id="1">Gabriel | ENG.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="1">Rafael | ENG.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="1">Samuel | ENG.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="1">Alex | ENG.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="1">Ricardo | ENG.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="2">Felipe | ADS.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="2">Cesar | ADS.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="2">Pedro | ADS.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="2">Maria | ADS.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="2">Ana | ADS.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="3">Lucas | ARQ.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="3">Miguel | ARQ.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="3">David | ARQ.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="3">Julia | ARQ.</li>
      <li class="aluno" id="3">Alice | ARQ.</li>
    </ol>
</div>

<div class="lista-grupo">
  <h3>Grupo</h3>
       <ol id="grupo">
            <li class="lider" id="1">Eu | ENG.</li>
      </ol>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
      .lista-alunos, .lista-grupo{
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        width: 270px;
        height: 270px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #F7F7F7;
      }
      #lista{
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: 205px;
      }
      #lista, #grupo{
        padding-left: 20px;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }
      .aluno, .lider{
        margin: 3px;
        padding: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .aluno{
        background: #CACACA; 
      }
      .selecionado, .lider{
        background: #A1B3A1;
      }
```

Comment: _"Preciso aplicar uma regra de negocio onde obrigatoriamente o usuário deve escolher dois alunos de cada curso"_ - queres selecionar dois de cada vêz ou impedir de selecionar mais do que dois de cada curso?

Comment: impedir de selecionar mais do que dois de cada curso

Comment: Amigao, não entendi muito bem, você deseja contar quais divs? Me responde aqui que quando eu fizer eu edito com o resultado.

Comment: Na div Grupo deve ter dois alunos de cada curso obrigatoriamente pra validar.

Exemplo de um grupo válido:

dois alunos de ENG, dois de ARQ e dois de ADS

Comment: Podes explicar a lógica de `selecionado`? quando e o quê fica selecionado quando clicas?

Comment: Foi uma maneira que encontrei pra alterar a cor dos alunos inseridos no grupo, e remover caso ele volte para a lista de alunos. Ou seja tem uma classe no CSS  .selecionado com backgroud verde, quando ele vai para o grupo recebe essa classe, quando sai do grupo remove a classe. tentei add direto pelo estilo, mas mudavam a das duas listas quando clicava

Comment: O líder também conta como aluno nos duplicados?

Comment: amigão, o html e o javascript que vc disponibilizou não bem formatados, fica complicado em arrumar, por favor coloque o codigo real, para q eu possa adaptar seu codigo com o contador

Comment: sim o lider conta, ele já vem quando a página é carregada. no caso é o próprio ususario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em cada documento (ie. em cada "página HTML") as IDs têm de ser únicas. Essa é a diferênça fundamental entre ID e class. ID é única e class é para aplicar a grupos de elemento.

Se esse `id` está relacionado por exemplo com algo que vem da base de dados podes guardar essa informação no elemento num campo `data-`. Assim o elemento tem a informação que queres e podes na mesma agrupá-los. Uma classe também funcionaria, depende do que precisas, e desde que dê para agrupar.

Nesse caso de usares `data-id` podes fazer assim no jQuery/JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $(".aluno").click(function() { //EVENTO CLICK
        var aluno = this;
        var campo = aluno.parentElement.id == 'lista' ? '#grupo' : '#lista';
        var alunosGrupo = $("#grupo li"); // se o lider não contar podes usar "#grupo .aluno"

        if (aluno.parentElement.id == 'lista') {
            var duplos = alunosGrupo.get().filter(function(el) {
                return aluno.dataset.id == el.dataset.id;
            });
            if (duplos.length > 1) return;
        }
        if (alunosGrupo.length <= 5) $(campo).append(aluno); //ANEXA NA DIV GRUPO
        else return;

        aluno.classList.toggle('selecionado');
    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p3wb04k9/1/

Comment: Voteup, funcionou aqui perfeitamente, não sei por que no meu js fiddle o javascript q ele disponibilizou não funcionou

Comment: Sim no sistema essa informação vai vir do Banco de dados, obrigado pela ajuda está funcional sim. Preciso estudar os métodos que utilizou pra eu entender linha por linha, haha. Mas muito obrigado Sergio

Answer (score 1):

o primeiro erro no seu html, é que o seu id se repete, lembrese que o id serve para identificar o elemento HTML e não o curso.

se precisar adicionar valores referente ao seu negocio no HTML, utilize propriedades `data-custom`, como por exemplo `data-curso='1'` ou `data-aluno='33'`

uma vez feito isto, você pode contar a quantidade de alunos na `div#grupos` que estão no mesmo curso, e não mover o aluno para o grupo se satisfazer a condição.

no exemplo abaixo estou assumindo que o aluno logado possui `data-aluno='0'`, mas você pode criar uma propriedade nova, como `data-self='true'`

o restante da logica, é para mover o aluno para a sua possição antiga na outra lista (estou ordenando pelo `id` do `aluno`)

```js
var alunos = document.querySelector("#alunos .content");
var grupos = document.querySelector("#grupos .content");

var pessoas = document.querySelectorAll(".content div[data-aluno]");
var moverPessoa = function (atual, destino, id) {
  var irmaos = destino.querySelectorAll("div[data-aluno]");
  irmaos = [].filter.call(irmaos, function (aluno, indice) {    
    return parseInt(atual.dataset.aluno) < parseInt(aluno.dataset.aluno);
  });
  
  if (irmaos.length == 0) {    
    destino.appendChild(atual);
  } else {    
    destino.insertBefore(atual, irmaos[0]);
  }
}

var onPessoaClick = function (event) {
  var atual = event.target;
  var id = parseInt(atual.dataset.aluno);
  var origem = atual.parentElement;
  var destino = origem == alunos ? grupos : alunos;
  
  if (id == 0) {
    alert('Não é possivel remover a si mesmo do Grupo');
    return;
  }
  
  if (origem == alunos) {
    var pessoas = destino.querySelectorAll("div[data-aluno]");
    var mesmoCurso = [].filter.call(pessoas, function (aluno, indice) {    
      return atual.dataset.curso == aluno.dataset.curso;
    });
    if (mesmoCurso.length == 2) {
      alert('Não é possivel mover mais alunos deste curso para o grupo');
      return;
    }
  }
    
  moverPessoa(atual, destino, id);
};

[].forEach.call(pessoas, function (pessoa, indice) {
  pessoa.addEventListener("click", onPessoaClick);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#alunos {
  left: 0px;
}

#grupos {
  right: 0px;
}

.container header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 30px Cambria;
  background-color: gainsboro;  
}

.container .content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container .content div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font: normal 20px Calibri;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gainsboro;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section id="alunos" class="container">
  <header>Alunos</header>
  <div class="content">
    <div data-aluno="1" data-curso="1">Gabriel | ENG.</div>
    <div data-aluno="2" data-curso="1">Rafael | ENG.</div>
    <div data-aluno="3" data-curso="1">Samuel | ENG.</div>
    <div data-aluno="4" data-curso="1">Alex | ENG.</div>
    <div data-aluno="5" data-curso="1">Ricardo | ENG.</div>
    <div data-aluno="6" data-curso="2">Felipe | ADS.</div>
    <div data-aluno="7" data-curso="2">Cesar | ADS.</div>
    <div data-aluno="8" data-curso="2">Pedro | ADS.</div>
    <div data-aluno="9" data-curso="2">Maria | ADS.</div>
    <div data-aluno="10" data-curso="2">Ana | ADS.</div>
    <div data-aluno="11" data-curso="3">Lucas | ARQ.</div>
    <div data-aluno="12" data-curso="3">Miguel | ARQ.</div>
    <div data-aluno="13" data-curso="3">David | ARQ.</div>
    <div data-aluno="14" data-curso="3">Julia | ARQ.</div>
    <div data-aluno="15" data-curso="3">Alice | ARQ.</div>
  </div>
</section>

<div id="grupos" class="container">
  <header>Grupo</header>
  <div class="content">
    <div  data-aluno="0" data-curso="1">Eu | ENG.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, está funcional também assim como o do Sergio. E bom ver meios diferentes de resolver vou ganhando experiencia

Answer (score 0):

crie uma variavel e coloque a `li` lá dentro com

```
var li = document.getElementById("id_da_li");
```

depois faz

```
li.getAttribute("id");
```

ai você faz um `if` dizendo que se o `id` for igual a `1`
adiciona no array com o método `.push(li);` e adiciona na `div`
ai você conta quantos  elementos tem no array
e faz outro `if` dizendo que se tiver mais de dois elementos não pode mais adicionar nenhum

Comment: Demetrius, no HTML não pode haver IDs duplicados...